# How to disable JQTE editor?

Tags: jquery, jqte

i am using [JQTE](http://jqueryte.com/documentation)  editor. i want to disable this editor on some condition.that after this condition  edit can't be done in this.

how will i do this?

any help appreciated .

Comment: Just don't call `$(element).jqte()`? I don't really see what the problem is...

Comment: i want in jqueryte editor edit functionality not work. @Lix

Comment: It doesn't look like the editor supports a "read only" mode. If you don't want the content to be editable, just don't call the editor and place your content in some other element.

Comment: in editor i want user edit the html as their requirement and when everything is fine then doc created and editor will disable. @Lix

Comment: don't down-vote down-voter give the valid reason for downvote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in [JQTE Editior](http://jqueryte.com/documentation) contain a property **contenteditable** by default it is true if we set false then it is in readonly mode

```
 $("#jqte editior id").find(".jqte_editor").attr("contenteditable","false");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".jqte_editor").prop('contenteditable','false');
```